# How can I check for duplicates in my linked list

Tags: c

I'm learning C recently and I'm trying to read from file details of book. A book has an author, title and a label. A book can have more than one label. If that is the case, the details should be sorted according to the authors name. For example:

this is my input file.

```
Plato; Feast; philosophy
Shakespeare; Hamlet; tragedy, baroque
Cormen; Algorithms; computer science, handbook
Mickiewicz; Pan Tadeusz; classics, romance, reading
Aquinas; Summa of Theology; philosophy, Medieval
```

I want to categorize books based on their labels, if the labels have more than 1 books under it (like for philosophy, the details should be merged).

```
philosophy  -> (Aquinas; Summa of Theology)-> (Plato; Feast) 
|
V
tragedy     -> (Shakespeare; Hamlet)
|
V
baroque     -> (Shakespeare; Hamlet)
....
```

**Here is my code so far**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



struct authors {//authors struct to store the author's name and title of the book

    char *author;
    struct authors *next_author;

};
struct authors *head_author = NULL;

struct labels {// label struct for storing the labels

    char *label;
    struct labels *next_label;
    struct authors *authors_data;
};
struct labels *head_label = NULL;


//=============function Prototypes===============
void insert_authors(char *value);
void append_authors(struct authors** head_ref, char *new_data);
void print_authors();


int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char container[1024];
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(container, sizeof(container), fp)){

        /*removing trailing \n from the lines*/
        size_t len = strlen(container);
        if (len > 0 && container[len-1] == '\n') {
        container[--len] = '\0';
        }
        /*string toking the data from the input file*/
        char *values = strtok(container, ";,");//first call to strtok
        char *values2 = strtok(NULL, ";,");// second call to strtok

        char con[100];
        /*(first and second call to the strtok gets me the authors & title like this:)
        Plato Feast, Shakespeare Hamlet,Cormen Algorithms, Mickiewicz Pan Tadeusz,
        Aquinas Summa of Theology*/
        strcpy(con, values);
        strcat(con, values2);
        char *dpcon = strdup(con);
        //printf("%s\n", con);

        /*The 3rd call to strtok starts the labels for me like this:
        philosophy, tragedy, computer science,classic and philosophy*/
        char *values3 = strtok(NULL, ";,");//THREE
        char *dpvalues3 = strdup(values3);
        //printf("%s\n", values3);

        /*sending the authors and labels to my authors list*/
        append_authors(&head_author, dpvalues3);
        append_authors(&head_author, dpcon);

        char *values4 = strtok(NULL, ";,");//FOUR
        char *dpvalues4 = strdup(values4);
        //printf("%s\n", values4);
        append_authors(&head_author, dpvalues4);

        char *values5 = strtok(NULL, ";,");//FIVE
        char *dpvalues5 = strdup(values5);
        //printf("%s\n", values5);
        append_authors(&head_author, dpvalues5);
        /*strtok ends here and the 5th call finished reading the labels*/

    }

    fclose(fp);

    print_authors();

    return 0;
}



void insert_authors(char *value) {

    struct authors *temp = (struct authors*)malloc(sizeof(struct authors));
    temp->author = value;
    temp->next_author = NULL;
    if(head_author != NULL) { temp->next_author = head_author;}
    head_author = temp;


}
void print_authors() {

    struct authors* temp = head_author;

    while(temp != NULL) {

        printf(" %s\n",temp->author);
        temp = temp->next_author;
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

How Can I checked for duplicate label with this function and link each label to its respective author's detail?

Example

```
philosophy  -> (Aquinas; Summa of Theology)-> (Plato; Feast) 
|
V
tragedy     -> (Shakespeare; Hamlet)
|
V
baroque     -> (Shakespeare; Hamlet)
```

Thus:

```
void append_authors(struct authors** head_ref, char *new_data)
{

    struct authors* new_node = (struct authors*) malloc(sizeof(struct authors));

    struct authors *last = *head_ref;  

    new_node->author  = new_data;


    new_node->next_author = NULL;


    if (*head_ref == NULL)
    {
       *head_ref = new_node;
       return;
    }


    while (last->next_author != NULL)
        last = last->next_author;

    last->next_author = new_node;
    return;
}
```

Comment: The question is missing?

Comment: You have asked this [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999666/linked-list-and-struct-in-c-programming) already. Except this time you've provided even less information (at least the previous question had some sample incorrect output). Please review the Stackoverflow help pages. Particularly [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For starters, you need to ask a specific question. Not just dump the code as then we don't know what help you are requesting.

Comment: Actually, I see within your code this comment: `i can check for duplicate labels but how to make them linked to my authors details is my headache`. Is that your question? If so, I suggest you put it into your question body and not as comments in the code where it is easily missed.

Comment: Thanks Kaylum. let me edit my post for better question